# Python - Convert string to image

Tags: python, parsing, xml-parsing, apk

I'm using https://github.com/appknox/pyaxmlparser to parse apk.

There is an property to get icon data :

```
apk.icon_data
```

When i print the output i have a string like this :

> \x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00R\xd

(It's too long )

What is this ?

How can i use this string to get a real image file ? Or even convert it to Base64 format

Comment: it seems to be the bytes that compose a PNG file - try writing them to a file with .png extension then open it with your image viewer

Comment: Thanks. i'm going to check this @nosklo

Answer (score 0):

apk.icon_data returns the value in byte-array(unicode UTF-16). In Python, Pillow supports byte-array to image conversion. You can checkout this [issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4097) for details -

```
import sys
from pyaxmlparser import APK
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

apk = APK ('apk/file/path.apk')

LEFT_THUMB = apk.icon_data

stream = BytesIO(LEFT_THUMB)

image = Image.open(stream).convert("RGBA")
stream.close()
image.save('out.png')
```